# ARKit SceneKit ARSCNView with Positional Audio SCNAudioPlayer WILL NOT STOP playing

Tags: audio, scenekit, arkit, arscnview

Running ARKit 2.0 with an ARSCNView. iOS12
The application uses multithreading, that's why these functions are being performed on the main thread (just to be sure). I also tried without explicitly performing the functions on the main thread too, with no avail.

I'm using an .aiff sound file but have also tried a .wav. No joy.

I even tried removing audioNode_alarm from the node hierarchy & the sound still plays. I even remove the ARSCNView from the view hierarchy and the sound STILL plays. FFS

From what I can see, I'm doing things EXACTLY as I'm supposed to, to stop the audio from playing. The audio simply will not stop no matter what I try. Can anyone think why?!

```
weak var audioNode_alarm: SCNNode!
weak var audioPlayer_alarm: SCNAudioPlayer?

func setupAudioNode() {

    let audioNode_alarm = SCNNode()
    addChildNode(audioNode_alarm)
    self.audioNode_alarm = audioNode_alarm

}

func playAlarm() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in

        self.audioNode_alarm.removeAllAudioPlayers()

        if let audioSource_alarm = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "PATH_TO_MY_ALARM_SOUND.aiff") {

            audioSource_alarm.loops = true
            audioSource_alarm.load()
            audioSource_alarm.isPositional = true
            let audioPlayer_alarm = SCNAudioPlayer(source: audioSource_alarm)
            self.audioNode_alarm.addAudioPlayer(audioPlayer_alarm)
            self.audioPlayer_alarm = audioPlayer_alarm

        }

    }

}

func stopAlarm() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in

        self.audioNode_alarm?.removeAudioPlayer(self.audioPlayer_alarm!)
        self.audioNode_alarm?.removeAllAudioPlayers()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is stopping the sound and removing the player by

```
yourNode.audioPlayers.forEach { audioLocalPlayer in
  audioLocalPlayer.audioNode?.engine?.stop()
  yourNode.removeAudioPlayer(audioLocalPlayer)
}
```

According to the documentation [*SCNAudioPlayer*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaudioplayer) has [*audioNode*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaudioplayer/1522747-audionode), which is supposed to be used "to vary parameters such as volume and reverb in real time during playback".

*audioNode* is of *AVAudioNode* type, so if we jump to [*engine*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudionode/1386896-engine) prop and its [*type*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/AVAudioEngine) definition, we'll find all the controls we need.

Comment: I finally got to test this out. You hit the nail right on the head. It was exactly the audioLocalPlayer.audioNode?.engine?.stop() that I needed. Thank you :)